# Color box with yellow border

Tags: tcolorbox, colorbox

How can I modify to produce something like this?
[image]

I tried this code for colorbox but I can't see the yellow border

```
\newtcolorbox{colorbox}[1]{
    breakable,
    title=#1,
    colback=white,
    colbacktitle=green!20!white,
    coltitle=black,
    fonttitle=\bfseries,
    bottomrule=0pt,
    toprule=0pt,
    leftrule=2pt,
    rightrule=0pt,
    titlerule=0pt,
    arc=0pt,
    outer arc=0pt,
    colframe=red   }
```

Comment: Please, provide minimum working examples, from `\documentclass` to `\end{document}` with all involved packages instead of short snipets of code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The yellow lines that you show are probably artifacts because they are no drawn with your code (`rightrule=0pt`,...).

If you want to see them, draw them with certain width and if you want the left red line, draw it with an extra `borderline`.

```
\documentclass[border=2mm]{standalone}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\newtcolorbox{mycolorbox}[1]{
    enhanced,
    breakable,
    title=#1,
    colback=white,
    colbacktitle=green!20!white,
    coltitle=black,
    fonttitle=\bfseries,
    boxrule=.5pt,
    arc=0pt,
    outer arc=0pt,
    colframe=yellow!80!orange,
    borderline west={2pt}{0pt}{red}   }

\begin{document}

\begin{mycolorbox}{Remarque}
\lipsum[1]
\end{mycolorbox}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your help!